# How to access array within PHP object

Tags: php, object

I know this question is a little n00b but I am struggling to work out to how to access the array 'ta[]' within the PHP object below. Usually I would have no problem but because my key contains the brackets i.e. 'ta[]' I can't wrap my head around how to access it, I guess I somehow need to escape it..?

I have tried most combinations such as..

```
object->ta[]
object["ta[0]"]
object["ta[]"]
object->ta[0]
```

Any help welcome!

```
object(stdClass)#6 (11) {
 ["tc"]=> string(4) "4500"
    ["tct"]=> string(1) "1"
    ["pd"]=> string(2) "AT"
    ["df"]=> string(10) "08/04/2016"
    ["dt"]=> string(10) "08/08/2016"
    ["nt"]=> string(1) "2"
    ["ta[]"]=> array(2)
       {
       [0]=> string(2) "40"
       [1]=> string(2) "35"
       }
    ["rc"]=> string(2) "US"
    ["rs"]=> string(2) "AR"
    ["cc"]=> string(2) "US"
    ["dfp"]=> string(10) "07/30/2016"
}
```

Comment: The duplicate exactly shows how you can access nested objects and arrays. It also covers your case where you have an invalid property name. So it answers your question.

Comment: touché ok fair enough missed that

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should do it

```
$obj->{"ta[]"};
```

Brace notation (using `{}`) does the same thing for accessing object properties as bracket notation (using `[]`) does for accessing array keys: It lets you define the property name as an expression.

Which in this case is just a simple string but could could be any other expression. To prove that with a (silly) example:

```
function ta() {
    return 'ta';
}

$obj = new stdClass;
$obj->{ta() . '[]'} = ['a', 'b'];
echo $obj->{"ta[]"}[1]; // b
```

Comment: perfect thank you, I confirm $obj->{"ta[]"}[0] works. Can you explain why?

Comment: Yeah, added more detail

Comment: Great thanks Peter makes sense - related subject, how would you access this within a template engine such as Twig? If not will raise a separate question. Thanks again!

Comment: I wouldn't, personally. I'd code around it. But, there is a twig function for this very thing http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/functions/attribute.html